# How to Use Kafka to Buffer MySQL Writes?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

After reaching some bottlenecks with the MySQL cluster my application uses (too many connections, deadlocks), I've been advised to queue all the writes using Kafka or Redis. A near real-time solution sounds, indeed, much better than having database connection errors in production, so I went for this recommendation.

However, I'm having troubles understanding where does Kafka (or a Redis stream) fit in my architecture. I currently use multiple MySQL servers with an HAProxy in front, then split read and write queries to different ports, to prevent the cluster from going out of sync. Each port is then directed to one server (in case of write queries) or many servers (in case of read queries).

I assume I would have to configure the write endpoint so that all write queries go through Kafka first, but it seems like I simply know too little to connect the dots based on the tutorials I've been watching (most examples turn certain MySQL tables into streams, but that would be too late for my use case).

My question would be: is there a simple way to redirect SQL queries to Kafka (something like switching the MySQL host and port configuration to Kafka or using some kind of plug-in) or do I have to write my own adapter?

(I'm using PHP with Laravel for my app)

Comment: Why would you have *too many* connections to MySQL? Are you using connection-pooling? Are these actual TCP connections or MySQL sessions? Using a buffer-layer in-front of MySQL just seems like the wrong solution.

Comment: "I'm using PHP with Laravel for my app" - ah, **there's your problem**. The current set-up you have (PHP with Laravel, with stock configuration), won't scale (e.g. PHP can't pool connections because it doesn't stay in-memory). Have you looked at using PHP's various `mysqlnd_*` extensions? You probably want `mysqlnd_mux` (for connection multiplexing) and `mysqlnd_ms` for replication and load-balancing.

Comment: I think making a message queue between is not a good practice.The message can only keep order in partition, which can not guarantee the consistency of result. For example, if you have multiple partitions for write topic, and have not set a rule for partition choosing, when you update an int field to 1 and then update it to 2, it is possible you get result value 1 or 2.There is similar issue between read and write operations.